# how to use Picasso to set image from mp3 files

Tags: android, picasso, android-music-player, mediametadataretriever

i am currently working on musicplayer. I want to laod my mp3 file imageArt using Picasso. But the main problem is how can i get that imageArt and set to picasso.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for how to use Picassor to load a picture into one of your imageview in Android?
See their documentation, it is given there. Self explanatory also.

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .into(imageView)
```

If you do not want to load from some url but already have it in the resources folder, then also the example is provided already there.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
```

Comment: i have only bitmap of image nothing else. how do i set bitmap instead of url